# Friend function declaration/definition inside a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend-function

Consider a class inside a namespace. The definition of the class declares a friend function.

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
        friend void baz();
    };
}
```

This should, based on what I know, declare `baz()` as a member of the innermost enclosing namespace, i.e. `Foo`.

Therefore, I expected the following definition for `baz()` to be correct:

```
void Foo::baz() { }
```

However, GCC (4.7) gives me an error.

```
error: ‘void Foo::baz()’ should have been declared inside ‘Foo’
```

Several solutions seem to work:

- Declare `baz()` outside the class.

  ```
  namespace Foo
  {
      void baz();

      class Bar
      {
          friend void baz();
      };
  }
  ```
- Define `baz()` inside the namespace.

  ```
  namespace Foo
  {
      class Bar
      {
          friend void baz();
      };
  }
  ...
  namespace Foo
  {
      void baz() { }
  }
  ```
- Compile with the `-ffriend-injection` flag, which eliminates the error.

These solutions seem to be inconsistent with the general rules of declaration/definition in C++ I know.

Why do I have to declare `baz()` twice?
Why is the definition otherwise only legal inside a namespace, and illegal with the scope resolution operator?
Why does the flag eliminate the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do I have to declare baz() twice?

Because the friend declaration doesn't provide a usable declaration of the function in the namespace. It declares that, if that function is declared in that namespace, it will be a friend; and if you were to *define* a friend function inside a class, then it would be available via argument-dependent lookup (but not otherwise) as if it were declared in the namespace.

> Why is the definition otherwise only legal inside a namespace, and illegal with the scope resolution operator?

Because it hasn't been (properly) declared in the namespace, and a function can only be defined outside its namespace (with scope resolution) if it has been declared.

> Why does the flag eliminate the error?

Because the flag causes the friend declaration to act as a declaration in the namespace. This is for compatibility with ancient dialects of C++ (and, apparently, some modern compilers) in which this was the standard behaviour.

Comment: This is not 100% true. It does declare a function at namespace level, and you can provide a definition without any other declaration. What `friend` does not is provide the equivalent declaration in the enclosing namespace scope for you. But if you don't need it (i.e. if ADL can find the inner declaration) it is not needed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: OK, I've rephrased slightly. I think it's more like the truth now.

Comment: I still not agree with the conclusions that you obtain, as I don't agree with the premise that the code should not compile.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It shouldn't compile because, per the standard quote in my comment to your answer, the name is not found by qualified lookup without a namespace-level declaration.

Comment: So what you are saying is that 7.3.1.2/2 does not only require the entity to be declared, but also to be found by qualified lookup. Still not 100% sure, but the tests in different compilers and rereading the standard with your help makes me doubt --removed the -1, pending an authoritative answer :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Without name lookup, it couldn't find the declaration; and without the declaration, it can't be defined. (Unfortunately, I don't have time to dredge up all the relevent sections of the standard).

Answer (score 2):

The first piece of code should compile:

```
namespace A {
   struct B {
      friend void foo();
   };
}
void A::foo() {}
```

Although it that particular function cannot be *used* unless you also provide a declaration at namespace level. The reason is that friend declarations are only seen through Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL), but `foo` does not depend on `A::B`, and thus the compiler will never look inside that type.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that shouldn't compile, and my compiler agrees. `error: ‘void A::foo()’ should have been declared inside ‘A’`

Comment: @MikeSeymour: What compiler are you using? Sun CC, VS and clang accept it; xlC_r and gcc reject it. At the same time, if this was not a declaration, how could it accept an inline definition (and this works in all compilers): `struct B { friend void foo() {} };`?

Comment: I, too, get an error (GCC 4.7). What does the standard have to say about this?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: gcc 4.6

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: C++11 7.3.1.2/3: "The name of the friend is not found ... by qualified lookup until a matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope
"

Comment: 7.3.1.2/2 *Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that namespace by explicit qualification (3.4.3.2)
of the name being defined, provided that the entity being defined was already declared in the namespace* 7.3.1.2/3 *[...]If a friend declaration in a nonlocal class first declares a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing
namespace.* Now the question is whether to provide the definition you need the declaration to be *found by qualified lookup* or the fact that it exist suffices

Comment: That is, depending on whether 7.3.1.2/2 is read strictly as *the entity being defined was already declared*, or as *there must be a declaration at namespace level*, or if there is an implied *the entity being defined must be found by qualified lookup* you can go one way or another.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I don't pretend to understand the details of name lookup; but surely since "Name lookup associates the use of a name with a declaration", it's necessary to perform name lookup here to determine whether the function is declared?