# What is this so called lookup in namespace function definition?

Tags: c++, c++11, lookup, language-lawyer

§3.4.1/9 in the C++11 Standard says:

> Name lookup for a name used in the definition of a friend function
>   (11.3) defined inline in the class granting friendship shall proceed
>   as described for lookup in member function definitions. If the friend
>   function is not defined in the class granting friendship, name lookup
>   in the friend function definition shall proceed as described for
>   lookup in namespace member function definitions.

My interpretation of this paragraph is that friend functions **defined in the class granting friendship** follow the rules in the previous paragraph (3.4.1/8). But what about the next case, i.e., where the friend function is **not** defined in the class granting friendship? What is this, so called lookup in namespace function definition? Would that be paragraph 6? I'm not sure.

Comment: You should see this it may help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718166/friend-function-declaration-definition-inside-a-namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that refers to 3.4.1§6. Quoting the leading sentence of that paragraph:

> A name used in the definition of a function following the function's *declarator-id* that is a **member of namespace `N`** ...

(emphasis mine)

Comment: How can you be so sure about this?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Because a name inside a friend function is not in the definition of any `class X`?

Comment: I'm finally convinced it's paragraph 6. Thanks (+1).

Comment: That 3.4.1p9 is not really clear. Is there a contradiction here? `void f(); struct A { friend void f() { X x; } typedef int X; }; struct B { friend void f(); };`? What is the lookup that is applied to the friend function definition? Shall it proceed "as described for lookup in namespace member function definitions" or "as described for lookup in member function definitions"?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `f()` is defined inline in class `A`, so it will follow lookup rules for member functions of class `A`. The other declarations of `f()` (which are *not* definitions) do not affect this - why do you think they should?

Comment: @Angew because "If the friend function is not defined in the class granting friendship, name lookup in the friend function definition shall proceed as described for lookup in namespace member function definitions.". `f` is not defined in `B` (which grants friendship), so the Standard says that the definition of `f` uses certain lookup forms.

Comment: I do *not* think that the other two declarations should affect this, but I *do* think that the Standard says they affect this (in a contradicting way, indeed).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb OK, I get your point now. You're right that it's contradictory. They probably meant the second "If" to be an `else if` ;-)