# Is there a way to call operator function through function pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, macros, z3

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982179/opposite-of-c-preprocessor-stringification) tells that we cannot unstringify something in C/C++. For example:

```
int i = 1 TO_IDENTIFIER("+") 2;
```

CANNOT be expanded to

```
int i = 1 + 2;
```

So I'm now thinking about an alternative:

Keep a `map` that maps the "string literal" to the "operator function" and then invoke the corresponding operator.

But I don't know whether there is a way to put operation function into `std::map` as it seems that `operator+` is not a unique name as a variable.

Here is the real-world problem I am encountered:

I have a token "$1 + $2" and I can parse them as strings

```
"$1" "+" "$2"
```

Then `"$1"` and `"$2"` are replaced with 2 objects whose type both are `z3::expr`. And I also need to replace `"+"` with the operation function whose declaration is:

```
friend z3::expr operator+(z3::expr const & a, z3::expr const & b);
```

Since there are other operators like `-`, `<`, I hope this can be done automatically. 
Firstly I define a type corresponding to the operator:

```
typedef z3::expr (*MyOperatorTy)(z3::expr const &a, z3::expr const &b);
```

Then `std::unordered_map` is generated:

- with type info in the map:

  ```
  std::unordered_map<std::string, MyOperatorTy> strOpMap (
    {"+", z3::expr operator+(z3::expr const & a, z3::expr const & b)},
    ...
  );
  ```
- Without type info(just like a normal function variable)

  ```
  std::unordered_map<std::string, MyOperatorTy> strOpMap (
    {"+", operator+},
    ...
  );
  ```

Neither works. I also tried `std::function<z3::expr(expr const&, z3::expr const)>` as the mapped_type, but still failed.

So is there any way to treat operator functions as a variable and call through function pointers?

Comment: Use `&` before a member function pointer.  To disambiguate over overloads, cast (implicitly or explicitly).

Comment: @chris But according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) it's just like `operator+`, right? How can it solve my problem? Furthermore, there are other operators needing mapping such as "&&" so these basic function is not enough.

Comment: @Yakk There is no member function here; and I just feel confused how to put the operator function into the `std::unordered_map`:-(

Comment: @HongxuChen An operator function with a fixed set of arguments?  `static_cast<Signature>(&Namespace::operator+)` assuming you put `operator+` for your type in the same Namespace as your type (as you should).  So `static_cast< z3::expr(*)(z3::expr const&, z3::exprt const&) >( &z3::operator+ )`.  At least I think that should work.

Comment: Thanks, that seems the answer. I find I need to additionally declare the operator+ inside namespace z3, as [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718166/friend-function-declaration-definition-inside-a-namespace) and then everything goes fine.

Answer (score 1):

`&foo` is a problem when `foo` denotes an overload set. And in any sizeable program, `operator+` will be overloaded. The problem can be resolved if there's a context in which `&foo` is used which allows overload resolution, such as assigning `&foo` to a variable with function pointer type. That type is then used for overload resolution.

In your case, however, you're tyring to populate an `std::initializer_list`. *Any* overload of `operator+` can be on that list.

Luckily, another situation also allows overload resolution: a cast. So,

```
typedef z3::expr (*MyOperatorTy)(z3::expr const &a, z3::expr const &b);

#define STR(var) #var
#define z3Op(var) \
   static_cast<MyOperatorTy> (operator##var## (z3::expr const &a, z3::expr const &b))
#define StrOpPair(var) \
  { STR(var), z3Op(var) }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that I should use `std::initializer_list`. I find that @Yakk 's may be right. Also, it seems that there are some issues when concat `operator` and `+`; I don't know why, so I add [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072193/why-string-concat-macro-doesnt-work-for-this-case).