# Why string concat macro doesn't work for this "+" case?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, clang

### Short question:

Is it permitted to concat special signs such as `+`, `-` for the string concatenation macro `##`? For example,

```
#define OP(var) operator##var
```

will `OP(+)` be expanded to `operator+`?

### Exact problem:

```
#include "z3++.h"
#include <unordered_map>

namespace z3 {
z3::expr operator+(z3::expr const &, z3::expr const &);
}

typedef z3::expr (*MyOperatorTy)(z3::expr const &, z3::expr const &);

#define STR(var) #var
#define z3Op(var) static_cast<MyOperatorTy>(&z3::operator##var)
#define StrOpPair(var) \
  { STR(var), z3Op(var) }

void test() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, MyOperatorTy> strOpMap1{
      {"+", static_cast<MyOperatorTy>(&z3::operator+)}};  // fine
  std::unordered_map<std::string, MyOperatorTy> strOpMap2{StrOpPair(+)}; // error
}
```

For `strOpMap2`, using `clang++ -c -std=c++11`, it reports:

```
error: pasting formed 'operator+', an invalid preprocessing token
```

while using `g++ -c -std=c++11`, it gives:

```
error: pasting "operator" and "+" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

By reading [the manual by gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) I find it should be possible to concat, but why both compilers emit errors?

Comment: `operator +` are *two* tokens, not one.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas So concat macro result will only be ONE token? And why `operator +` are TWO tokens? `operator` and `+` should be recognized as one *operator function*, right?

Comment: `operator` is a keyword. To get what you want, `#define OP(var) operator var`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can paste punctuation to form other punctuation, e.g.

```
#define PASTE(a,b) a##b

int main()
{
     int i = 0;
     i PASTE(+,+);
     // i == 1 now
}
```

The `##` operator is for producing a valid *preprocessing token* from other preprocessing tokens. The result of pasting must be a valid preprocessing token.  So this is not valid:

```
PASTE(i,++)
```

because `i++` is not a preprocessing token; it's two adjacent tokens `i` and `++`.

The list of possible tokens is (N3797):

- header-name
- identifier
- pp-number
- character-literal
- user-defined-character-literal
- string-literal
- user-defined-string-literal
- preprocessing-op-or-punc
- each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above

Note: at the preprocessing stage, *keyword* does not exist; but after preprocessing, any identifiers which should be keyword are converted (semantically) into keywords. So you can build keywords by pasting shorter words.

In your code, `operator+` is two tokens: `operator` and `+`.  So you do not build it with `##`; you just do one then the other.

```
#define OP(punc) operator punc
```