# Why do I need to enclose the definition of this friend function in a namespace?

Tags: c++

Given a namespace `N` with a class `C` and a friend function `f` in a header file:

```
namespace N
{
class C
{
   friend void f();
}
}
```

If I define the friend function `f` in the cpp file like this:

```
void N::f()
{
    ...
}
```

it does not compile. If I define it like this:

```
namespace N
{
void f()
{
    ...
}
}
```

it **does compile**. Why?

*I'm using gcc 4.4, but I tried a similar example in Coliru compiling for C++14 and got the same behavior*

Comment: Is the namespace N declared before `void N::f()`?

Comment: Could you try a little thing: change friend declaration to `friend void ::f();`?

Comment: @grek40 Yes, it is declared in the header file, which is included by the cpp file, where I define the function. I noticed a typo in the question, I'm fixing it.

Comment: -- removed wrong comment --

Comment: @hauron If I try to declare `f` as global as you suggest, I get `main.cpp:6:21: error: 'void f()' should have been declared inside '::'`. Which I also don't understand quite well. Check http://cpp.sh/37n6a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the days of GCC 4.7 all up to now 7.0, GCC doesn't introduce a new name into the enclosing namespace as described by:

[basic.scope.pdecl/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#scope.pdecl-11)

> Friend declarations refer to functions or classes that are members of
>   the nearest enclosing namespace, but they do not introduce new names
>   into that namespace.

Although, **GCC** provides a compatibility switch (`-ffriend-injection` to inject the name into the enclosing namespace). However, right from **clang** 3.1 to 4.0, **clang** injects the declaration into the enclosing namespace.

Although such function can be found via ADL: [namespace.memdef/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3)

> If a friend function or function template is called, its name may be
>   found by the name lookup that considers functions from namespaces and
>   classes associated with the types of the function arguments
>   ([basic.lookup.argdep](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep)).

---

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718166/friend-function-declaration-definition-inside-a-namespace), So, what all the compilers should honor is:

```
namespace N
{
    class C
    {
       friend void f();
    };

    void f();   //introduce the name
}

void N::f()     //define it
{ ... }
```

See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4fe2eaca2b0d73f)

Or the other way:

```
namespace N
{
    class C{
        friend void f();
    };
}

namespace N
{
    void f()
    { ... }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find the question you linked when I did my search. Thanks! I will vote for closing this question then, since it is nearly a duplicate. Although your answer provides as well a good insight. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If the symbol is declared inside namespace `N` prior to its definition, the definition as qualified name should work fine. Otherwise it's not working.

Following is true for visual studio.

Ok:

```
namespace N
{
    void f();
}
void N::f() { }
```

Not really ok, but working in visual studio:

```
namespace N
{
class C
{
   friend void f();
}
}
void N::f() { }
```

Not ok:

```
void N::f() { } // error, undefined N
```

Not ok:

```
namespace N
{
}
void N::f() { } // error, f is not a member of N
```

But I can't test on different compilers right now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion (check http://cpp.sh/4kcoy) and it does not compile with gcc. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Auron his answer is wrong. The name is not visible to normal qualified name lookup, but only to ADL

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What you say sounds quite interesting. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb thanks, edited to reflect the fact that visual studio is accepting the 2nd case non-standard.

Comment: @grek40 IIRC, some committee member said they discussed to make it valid, however I don't anymore remember where I read it. And I can't find a corresponding issue report about it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb probably a MS employed committee member, trying to adjust the standard to *someones* specific implementation :D